# Install Ubuntu alongside working dual boot (Windows 7 and Windows 10) - Win 7 not recognized by Ubuntu live USB

Tags: ubuntu, windows, boot-loader

I have a working dual boot system (Windows 7 Pro 64bit and Windows 10 Pro 64bit) and want to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a live USB stick in order to have a working triple boot system (please note that this settup is required and virtualization of Windows 7 is sadly not an option).

However: If I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 not both already installed Windows versions are recognized. I tried to install Ubuntu anyway before (same setup as described) but ended up loosing access to Windows 7.

Windows 10 dual boot (text is german - means: Select Operating System):
[image: working win dual boot]

Ubuntu live USB installation selection:
[image: ubuntu live USB installation screen]

Ubuntu installation step where I stopped:
[image]

Ubuntu installation screen when I select the "Something Else" option:
[image]
Please note that I have installed Windows 7 on a partition of 75GB and Windows 10 on a partition with 150GB, so I suppose the partition marked as 'unknown' should be the partition of Windows 10.
I have powered down Windows 10 turning of Fast Boot and Secure Boot is disabled via the BIOS settings.

I have searched various forums for answer related to my question but since I already have installed the exact same settup two times I'd rather have the advice of someone experienced in these matters if possible :-)

The laptop used is a Lenovo L560 and the harddisk is an SSD with 750GB
(although I do not think that is relevant to this case...)

The order in which I installed the operating systems is:
(1) Windows 7
(2) Windows 10

thanks in advance,
matthias

Comment: It can be done from the Windows side, i believe, but then it makes this question borderline topic here, and more suited for superuser than here.

Comment: So, you're saying that after installing Ubuntu thus booting to the typical Grub menu, when you select "Windows" there it doesn't show the some boot options as your first screenshot and instead boots Windows 10 directly?

Comment: @MichaelBay: I am a little bit ashamed to admit - I do not exactly remember the exact error message or the exact steps (via GUI boot instructions) which lead to the error. I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and had some sort of error while updating the packages via Internet during the installation (this resulted in some sort of error that informed me that the package manager was malefunctioning when I tried again)...

Comment: ... when I tried to boot windows I got an error that the partition tabel was corrupted and starting via the Windows 10 Installation disk and performing a chkdsk quite a few error where displayed. As a security measure I formated the harddisk anew via the console and performed a chkdsk again) - would you recommend that I simply try installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (as in the Ubuntu installation screen displayed) again ? might it be that I had the package manager error during the installation  of Ubuntu in my previous attempt ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: if this is the wrong forum for this sort of question we could move it of course. I posted here because I saw a few question converning similiar topics

Comment: I recommend nothing until you understand what you're doing. The APT error has nothing to do with multi boot.

Comment: understood - if this was a completely new situation and the desired output would be as described (turning a working dual boot win system into a triple boot system with ubuntu / grub on top - how would you proceed from the last shown Ubuntu installation step (considering the displayed informations concerning the partitions - e.g. the Win 10 partition not being shown as NTFS and the used space as marked as 'unknown') ? both Win systems are new and there is no actual danger of loosing data (ignoring the customizations and the updates to the operating systems)

Comment: Your using the old BIOS/MBR installation mode and that complicates things a little bit. However, Grub doesn't need to "see" the other Windows. It need to detect Win10 only, the OS in charge of the current dual boot, and chainload to it, i.e., selecting "Windows" in Grub should land you in the same boot options as shown in the first screenshot. If this is a UEFI machine then installing all OSes in the proper mode (UEFI/GPT) has great advantages.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comment of MichaelBay I realized that I indeed that not have the required knowledge to perform the required correct steps to achieve what I wanted to (I did not know the differences between BIOS/MBR and UEFI/GPT, which might not be required, but at least one should know that these two different installation modes exist and what you'd have to do to install operating systems in either one or the other mode).

Please note concerning my initial question: continuing from the installation step (Ubuntu) where I stopped with the option 'Install alongside Window' DID WORK this time and the reason it did not work in my previous attempt was probably due to an update error while downloading packages installing Ubuntu and a resulting harddisk error (as seen by my verification via chkdsk at my initial attempt).

However: 
As I read in that the correct approach would be to install ALL operating systems in the UEFI/GPT I tried to create a correct setup from the start and these where the steps which where successfull (at least for me).

As I believed that the required installation order is Win 7 -> than Win 10 -> than Ubuntu I tried with various approaches th install Win 7 in UEFI/GPT mode. According to Microsoft in order to do this you'd have to enter the BIOS settings, disable secure boot and set boot mode to UEFI only and activate CSM support. Than you'd normally start with the Win 7 installation DVD (SP1 included) selecting same sort of 'boot DVD in UEFI mode' and the Windows installation DVD would start in UEFI mode. However, as the option to start the DVD specifically in UEFI was not present (and even though my laptop is UEFI compatible - a lenovo l560, updating the BIOS with a tool lenovo provided did not change a thing, the BIOS GUI still looked like the old BIOS, no mouse or better resulation) the Win7 installation started in BIOS/MBR mode. Creating a bootable USB stick with rufus (and setting the stick to GPT mode) did not help either. Installing Win 7 in BIOS/MBR and than converting this installation to 
UEFI/GPT did not prove to be successfull as well...

What I did was the following (pretty sure that not all steps are required but still might be helpful to others):

Go into the BIOS settings (F1 or F2), disable secure boot and set boot mode to UEFI only and activate CSM support

Start with Win10 Installation DVD

When the installtion window opened I pressed SHILFT+F10 to enter the console and entered the following commands

1. diskpart
2. list disk (identifying the correct disk, in my case disk 0)
3. select disk 0
4. clean all (clean alone might have been enought - be warned that this will delete all partitions and data, so make sure you have selected the correct disk)
5. convert gpt (setting gpt mode)
6. list disk (to make sure that the gpt column is marked with an asterix)
7. exit (leave diskpart)
8. exit (leave the command line)

Create a partition and continue with the installation of Window 10 (via DVD)
When finished create a partition from within Windows 10 (installed OS) with the required partition size

Insert the Win7 installation DVD and start

Select the partition you created before as target partition and install
(at a certain point I got a warning the the partition order is not the way microsoft recommand for GPT - I ignored that)

Finish installation - now you can boot via the Windows boot manager both operating systems

Install Ubuntu (I chose 'Alongside the windows boot manager')

Actually all pretty simple (and probably the explanation here is an overkill) - the only important thing was that I could not get the Windows 7 DVD to boot into UEFI mode and the bootable rufus USB stick did not work either - I had to install Win 7 from within the already installed Win 10 OS to ensure Win 7 is indeed installed in UEFI mode)

quite a lot of words for such a little piece of information :-)

@MichaelBay: thanks a lot for your assistance - and yes, one should at least know what he is trying to achieve before starting...

Kind Regards,
Matthias